# C++ Printing empty 3D array initialized with new. Contains random numbers. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++

This is my first post, so please let me know if I am doing something wrong, forum-wise.

My code:

```
double (*test_2d)[3][3] = new double[3][3][3];

for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
{
    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
    {
        std::cout<<*(test_2d+0)[a][b]<<std::endl; //dereference to get 2d array from pointer
    };
};

for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
{
    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
    {
        std::cout<<*(test_2d+1)[a][b]<<std::endl; //dereference to get 2d array from pointer+1
    };
};

for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
{
    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
    {
        std::cout<<*(test_2d+2)[a][b]<<std::endl; //dereference to get 2d array from pointer+2
    };
};
```

When printing this, one or some of the values are extremely large such as in my screenshot.

My primary question:

When initializing a (double) multidimensional array with "new", should the values already be defined with default value of nan or 0.00? Also, is the screenshot showing that I am indexing the array wrong?

Appreciate the help.

This problem started in a project I was building using template recursion. To simplify the problem, I written the code shown here to ask a basic question about how new defines values in memory and if I indexed something wrong that lead to a very large number being outputted.[image]

Comment: `new` does not *initialize* anything. It simply allocates memory, and that memory contains whatever random content was in that location. Initializing means assigning a value to the array element. Your current code outputs information from uninitialized array elements, which can contain anything.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks Ken. So to clarify, new declares the memory only  and not define it, and if there was existing information in there, the print will output that. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, why would there be random content in memory if it was just allocated? Is this an example of undefined behavior when not defining a value inside a declared memory block? Thanks again!

Comment: @KenWhite Do you want to submit an answer so I can mark yours as the answer, or is it okay if I credit you and answer it myself on this post? Thanks

Comment: You can answer it. ::-) You can (after a short wait) accept your answer as correct, too. See [Can I answer my own question?)(http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Why are you using `+1` and `+2` on the pointer?  That looks like it would lead to an out-of-bounds access, which is definitely undefined behavior territory.

Answer (score 2):

From the comment above by @KenWhite:

`new` does not initialize anything. It simply allocates memory, and that memory contains whatever random content was in that location. Initializing means assigning a value to the array element. Your current code outputs information from uninitialized array elements, which can contain anything.

Comment: Actually this is only half correct.  It's true if you're allocating simple types like `double`, but if you're allocating class objects it will call the default constructor for each member of the array.